# Meaning of the word Сафир(ъ) in this passage?

Tags: перевод

I'd like to find out what the word Сафиръ means in this passage from an old textbook. I cannot find this word in any dictionary. I think it might mean "ambassador", but I'm not sure.

From [Pietro Motti's *Elementary Russian grammar*, 2nd ed., 1901, p. 56](https://archive.org/details/elementaryrussia00mottuoft/page/56/mode/2up):

- Image:

  > [image: Reading Exercise - Сафи́ръ на обѣ́дѣ. (transcription below)]
- Transcription:

  > ##### READING EXERCISE.
  >
  > ##### Сафи́ръ на обѣ́дѣ.
  >
  > Одна́ да́ма въ Берли́нѣ пригласи́ла одна́ждый знамени́таго Сафи́ра къ обѣ́ду.  У ней столъ былъ обста́вленъ сли́шкомь ску́по. По́слѣ обѣ́да спра́шиваетъ хозя́йка Сафи́ра: «Когда́ изво́лите опя́ть у меня́ обѣ́дать, любе́зный Сафи́ръ?» «Охо́тно сейча́съ!» отвѣ́тилъ гость.
  >
  > на обѣ́дѣ at dinner.
  > пригласи́ть, to invite.
  > обста́вленъ served, laid.
  > ску́по, avariciously.
  > опя́ть again.
  > гость guest.

Comment: Reading exercise from XIX century???

Comment: It is name of some person (It is why it capitalized)

Comment: @talex is right. It is a name. So correct question is who is this Saphir, which is not question about language. In this passage it is just a name of a character.

Comment: The capitalization is hardly an indication of a name since the first word is capitalized regardless of whether it's a name or not.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> САФИР Мориц Готлиб (Moritz
> Gottlieb Saphir, 1795-1858) - немецкий юморист и журналист.
>
> …
>
> Впервые обратил на себя внимание сборником стихов «Poetische Erstlinge» (1821). Издавал театральные и юмористические журналы, пользовавшиеся большим успехом. В Берлине издан был против С. памфлет, на к-рый он ответил брошюрой, выдержавшей 4 издания за неделю: «Der getodtete und dennoch lebende Saphir» (Убитый, но тем не менее живой Сафир, 1828). Литературная производительность С. весьма велика. В 1884 было издано собрание его избранных сочинений в 12тт., в 1890 - сочинения в 26тт. Наибольшим успехом пользовались «Fliegendes Album fur Ernst, Scherz, Humor...» (Летучий альбом серьезного, шуток, юмора и жизнерадостности, 1846), «Conversations-Lexikon fur Geistwitz und Humor» Словарь остроумия и юмора, 1851-1852, 2 Aufl., 1860, 3 Aufl., 1893), а также «Humoristische Abende» (Юмористические вечера, 1830), «Dumme Briefe» (Глупые письма, 1834) и др.

*Литературная энциклопедия. — В 11 т.; М.: издательство Коммунистической академии, Советская энциклопедия, Художественная литература. Под редакцией В. М. Фриче, А. В. Луначарского. 1929—1939.*

Answer (score 4):

The dictionaries say it's an alternative spelling of **сапфир** "sapphire", which makes no sense. On the other hand, **safîr سفير**  means "ambassador" in Arabic, from the root S-F-R meaning "travel", and it could be a term with a more specific meaning back in the day. I've never come across it in Russian, though.

Comment: Oh well, at least now I know that it wasn't a completely stupid question. I typed it (including the hard sign) into a search engine and the only other place I found was a play from 1815.

Comment: I'm also reminded of Nasreddin Hoja — a popular folk character across the Near East and Central Asia whose characteristic is this exact sort of dry wit (when he isn't just being silly).

Comment: Oh, I see! It's a proper name.

Comment: @NikolayErshov Do you think that it could be the meaning? Why is it capitalized then? Looks more like a name.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy It is in fact a name, and my guesswork here wasn't altogether relevant.

Comment: @R.I.P.30.12.21Baskakov_Dmitriy Isn't every first word capitalized in a sentence? It would've looked strange in lower case.

Comment: Excellent answer, Nikolay! You even referenced the Arabic. How very interesting!

Answer (score -1):

Словарь [татарских и тюркских имен(составитель неизвестен)](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/personal_names/9232/%D0%A1%D0%90%D0%A4%D0%98%D0%A0) дает следующее:

Сафир - посол, полномочный представитель.

Сафар - путешественник.

[Русско-татарский переводчик](https://sahifa.tj/tatarsko_russkij.aspx) дает следующее:

сәфир- сущ. посол, полномочный представитель.

Скорее всего были перепутаны слово "сафир" - посол, с личным именем Сафир. Оба слова могли быть в ходу, так как татары - мусульмане, и прочие мусульмане могли вполне себе знать как русский язык, так и арабский, по крайней мере употреблять некоторые понятия, через знания их значений в именах или из того же Корана.

У Даля и у Фасмера сафир=сапфир и пересечь с чем-то кроме одноименного камня не представляется возможным.

Однако, можно обнаружить еще такое пересечение, что:

Сафир-сапфир, возможно, от корня [bher](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*bher-#etymonline_v_52553) - то есть [носить/брать, выносливый](https://anti-fasmer.livejournal.com/1093805.html). Потому посол и путешественник, амбассадор -> миссионер.

Но, если по-простому, то сафир - посол. "Посол на обеде", "знаменитый посол" - вполне подходит.